# PHP Form not submitting on specific pages, same code

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have the following Form code:

```
<form method=post action='/zoeken.php'>
    <div style='position: relative;'>
        <input type=search name=zoeken_opdracht placeholder='Zoeken...' value="<?php echo $_POST['zoeken_opdracht']; ?>">
        <button name=zoeken><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

However, when I am submitting in on specific pages, it isn't submitting. The same code however works fine on all other pages (No product pages).

See examples of productpage here:
[Productpage (Form not working)](http://www.e-dealers.nl/Apple-Accu-iPhone-5-batterij.php)

You can find the other forms on any other page but the productpages. For instance the homepage.

Comment: There is no `input type="submit"` in form

Comment: where is the submit button?

Comment: If this is truely the exact code used else where, then you probably have some javascript on the other pages that is submitting the form, but not on this page

Comment: The form is not submitted by JavaScript anywhere. I already tried to submit this form with JavaScript, still no difference. The button tag is the equivalent of input type=submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I figured out that there was a preventDefault in my javascript code that was also triggered on the search form submission. I fixed this and now it works like a charm.

Thanks for the

Answer (score 0):

Change `button` with `submit`

Careful that there are errors in the type `search`, in the form `method`, in some `name` and `style`

```
    <form method="post" action="/zoeken.php">
        <div style="position:relative;">
            <input type="search" name="zoeken_opdracht" placeholder="Zoeken..." value="<?php echo $_POST['zoeken_opdracht']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="zoeken"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Already tried to add the type='submit' however, it doesn't make a difference. There are no errors (at least not mentioned)

Comment: @T.V.AvanHesteren - If you put the input and click submit what happens?

Comment: When placing the input type=submit, no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method=post action='/zoeken.php'>
<div style='position: relative;'>
    <input type="search" name="zoeken_opdracht" placeholder='Zoeken...' value="<?= $_POST['zoeken_opdracht']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" name=zoeken><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Already tried to add the type='submit' however, it doesn't make a difference.